# diff between END and EOF

Tags: bash, here-document

Is there any difference between:

```
cat <<END
    {"@json-stdio":true,"value":"$pack"}
END
```

and

```
cat <<EOF
    {"@json-stdio":true,"value":"$pack"}
EOF
```

?

Comment: there's no difference between `END` and `EOF`, but there's a big difference between  `<<END` and `<<'END'` or `<<"END"`; only the first will perform (variable & other) expansions in the here-document.

Comment: Yes spelling, and nothing else. Choose a word that is not in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; the word that delimits the here-document can be (almost) anything.

> 3.6.6 Here Documents
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only *word* (with no trailing blanks) is seen.

... where *word* is:

> A sequence of characters treated as a unit by the shell. Words may not include unquoted metacharacters

... and *metacharacters* are:

> A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a space, tab, newline, or one of the following characters: ‘|’, ‘&’, ‘;’, ‘(’, ‘)’, ‘<’, or ‘>’.

Comment: notice that you can include any of those characters in the here-doc delimiter (*including newlines* with `dash` and `ksh93`), provided that you're quoting it. Example: `printf 'cat <<" a () <> & "\nA\nB\n a () <> & \necho done\n' | bash` and `printf 'cat <<" a \n b "\nA\nB\n a \n b \necho done\n' | dash`